# What does "Objects did not meet prerequisites: Procedure WRITETOFILE is invalid" mean?

Tags: sql-server, database-migration

I am attempting to migrate on-prem Oracle database to an Azure SQL Server instance using the SQL Server Migration Assistant.  When running the Assessment Report I receive the above error on one of the Oracle schemas and have been unable to find an answer in Google.  I assume it is a permissions issue but unsure where since I have met all of the user permission prerequisites in both databases.

Comment: Can you compile that stored procedure in Oracle?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - There are multiple stored procedures in the database.  I assume that I can compile all of them since I meet all of the pre-reqs mentioned in the docs but I can't be 100% sure unless I try compiling them all.  So it is talking about stored procedures?  Ok.  I'll start from there.  Thank you.